# Asp.net core create interface for identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am creating an asp.net core web application and I am trying to create an interface for my db context in order to use it in my bussiness logic layer. The interface is made as followed:

```
public interface IAppDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

The Implementation of the Interface is as followed:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string> , IAppDbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is that when i Inject the interface and I try to use `_context.Users` it shows the error that:

```
'IAppDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no accessible extension method 'Users' accepting a first argument of type 'IAppDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
```

I understand that on the implementation, `_context.Users` comes from the parent class `IdentityDbContext`, but how can I also add it to the interface so I can use it? Thank you!

Comment: There is no point to implementing an interface here. An interface is for having multiple implementations all conform to a single contract. Here there will not ever be multiple implementations - just your one context class.

Comment: I am trying to implement https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders (clean architecture) to my application, and he uses an interface for the dbcontext in the business layer and the implementation on a different project. I believe he does this approach for unit testing. Since I am quite new to programming, you believe that this is not necessary and I can directly reference the persistence from the application layer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not necessary for testing. Just because someone threw some code online doesn't mean it's good or that you should follow the same way.

Comment: A lot of that is probably unnecessary. You don't need an interface. You shouldn't use repository/unit of work patterns with ORMs like EF. If you want abstraction, use a service layer or more advanced patterns like CQRS or microservices. Although, that should happen fluidly with the development of your app. In other words, start small. Create the barest unit of functionality and then refactor into patterns as necessary. The "necessary" part being key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Users to your interface. Try to update it following way:

```
public interface IAppDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am currently in the process of refactoring my application, when I finish it, I will test it and I will approve the answer if it works.